# Save OpenGL Rendering to Video

Tags: opengl, video

I have an OpenGL game, and I want to save what's shown on the screen to a video.
How can I do that? Is there any library or how-to-do-it?
I don't care about compression, I need the most efficient way so hopefully the FPS won't drop.

**EDIT:**
It's OpenGL 1.1 and it's working on Mac OSX though I need it to be portable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [caputre OpenGL window in X11 with fast framerate - possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615474/caputre-opengl-window-in-x11-with-fast-framerate-possible)

Comment: Which platform is the target here?  The solution may differ based on that.

Comment: Is now working on OSX, but as all the code is fairly portable, the solution to this should be too.

Comment: If this is a duplicate, then the above is wrong pick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There most certainly are great video capture software out there you could use to capture your screen, even when running a full screen OpenGL game.

If you are using new versions of OpenGL, as genpfault has mentioned you can use PBOs. If you are using legacy OpenGL (version 1.x), here's how you can capture the screen:

```
glFinish(); // Make sure everything is drawn
glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
glReadPixels(blx, bly, w, h, mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_BGRA);
```

where `blx` and `bly` are the bottom left coordinates of the part of the screen you want to capture (in your case `(0, 0)`) and `w` and `h` are the width and height of the box to be captured. See the reference for `glReadPixels` for more info, such as the last parameter.

Writing captured screen (at your desired rate, for example 24 fps) to a video file is a simple matter of choosing the file format you want (for example raw video), write the header of the video and write the images (image by image if raw, or image differences in some other format etc)

Comment: I tried screen capture software, but I get frame drops, and event if the game does not freezes for a few seconds, the video does. I need to capture at 60fps. If I can save directly to a video from the game, then I can fix the game update delta time to 1/60s, and the video will look smooth even if there is a freeze.

Comment: It's OpenGL 1.1 because the game works on mac and iphone too, so I guess PBOs are not an option, right?

Comment: 60fps video seems like overkill, but that's your choice. You can fix the framerate at 1/60s but capture every other frame (so capture on alternating frames). I don't remember which capture software I used on my previous computer, but I captured a starcraft II game and it was perfect (no freeze no frame drop). Surely, your game is less costly than starcraft II! You just need to search for a better software

Comment: I searched, and it looks like it is there from OpenGL 2.0, or you need to get the ARB_vertex_buffer_object extension which was introduced from version 1.4. Double check this though I'm not so sure

Comment: I don't get it, Shahbaz. If at some point there is a freeze that lasts for example, one second, I will get 60 (or 30) equal frames in the video. If instead I save the frame in the game after drawing it, it will look perfect in the video. I'm doing a video trailer for the game, so I need the video to look perfect.

Comment: @Damian, yes of course. However, I thought you meant the game freezes because of the video capture software. That's why I suggested a better one. If your game freezes on its own, then regardless of capturing, maybe you should work to get that fixed!

Comment: It freezes when the capture software is running :)

Comment: Then you most certainly need a better software if you are too lazy to write it on your own. If not, then you are like me: "Never use others work, write from scratch" :D It's fun!

Answer (score 2):

Use [Pixel Buffer Objects (PBOs)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html#pack).